# Is Azure Resource Manager faster then API calls?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-resource-manager

I'm currently developing an ASP.NET MVC application that makes use of Azure resources. I succeeded in using the Resource Manager and getting the same information using API calls.
Now i was wondering whether it's better to use ARM instead of doing API calls?
And performance-based, is ARM faster then API-calls?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARM provides you the automation way and to have a standard repeatable procedure to provision azure resources seamlessly. ARM template when called from powershell will internally be using the Azure management API architecture to achieve the provisioning and deployment.

Performance wise I believe it will all be more or less the same maybe if you call the API directly it will be quicker. But with API calls you are made to do all the due diligence yourself and deploying a large azure environment via API will involve meticulous planning and coding from your side.Whereas the ARM approach is templated for that purpose and it will help you streamline your ALM/ devops pipeline.

Comment: Thank you for this clear and fast answer! 
I asked this question because of the fact my organization has Classic resources which can only be accessed with an API call. ARM only supports the resources from the new portal. Therefor i had to mix ARM and API calls that basically did the same.

Comment: it is quite normal to have a mix of both. maybe you can have powershell scripts to handle both.